# Convert text file to avro using Pig script

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I am working on Text file to Avro conversion using pig script

`I have a text file in pipe delimited format located at /user/hduser/pig_input/abc.dat

`1|8|123|985|659856|10000000002546
1|8|123|985|659856|10000000002546
1|8|123|985|659856|10000000002546
1|8|123|985|659856|10000000002546
1|8|123|985|659856|10000000002546`

The Schema file is located at hdfs /user/hduser/pig_schema_files/abc.avsc

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "import_dummy",
  "doc" : "import_123dummy",
  "fields" : [ {
  "name" : "ID",
  "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
  "columnName" : "ID",
  "sqlType" : "3"
  }, {
  "name" : "TRANS_O",
  "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
  "columnName" : "TRANS_O",
  "sqlType" : "3"
 }, {
 "name" : "CARD_O",
 "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
 "columnName" : "CARD_O",
 "sqlType" : "3"
 }, {
 "name" : "SEQ_O",
 "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
 "columnName" : "SEQ_O",
 "sqlType" : "1"
 }, {
 "name" : "DATE_O",
 "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
 "columnName" : "DATE_O",
 "sqlType" : "3"
 }],"tableName" : "123dummy"}
```

Following is the script that I wrote

```
REGISTER /app/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
REGISTER /app/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/avro-1.3.7.jar
REGISTER /app/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/jackson-core-asl.jar
REGISTER /app/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/jackson-mapper-asl.jar
REGISTER /app/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/json-simple.jar
REGISTER /app/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/snappy-java.jar

textfile = load 'user/hduser/pig_input/abc.dat' using pigStorage('|');
STORE textfile INTO '/user/hduser/pig_output/' 
    USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('schema_file','/user/hduser/pig_schema_files/abc.avsc');
```

I am getting the following Error after running the script:

```
2015-02-03 09:46:56,369 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  -                                         ERROR 6000:<file script.pig, line 9, column 0> 
    Output Location Validation Failed for: '/user/hduser/pig_output/
    More info to follow:
    Output schema is null!
```

Comment: Any suggestion please??

Comment: Are you getting any error?. Can you paste the schema format of abc.avsc file ?

Comment: @SivasakthiJayaraman.. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: If your file is in HDFS , have your tried this option? "-f hdfs:///yourdirectory/abc.avsc"). Can you take a look at 'option' section in the link. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#AvroStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with CSV file, we have to read field names so that while writing `avro`, it will automatically map the field names.

```
textfile = load 'user/hduser/pig_input/abc.dat' using pigStorage('|') as (ID, TRANS_O,CARD_O,SEQ_O, DATE_O );
STORE textfile INTO '/user/hduser/pig_output/' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramakrishna for the reply..however I believe that the script would only map the records from text file with the column fields specified. The output file would only have field names with corresponding records but not the schema contained in it, as we are not providing any schema while loading the records.